# Como obter a linha de um determinado indice de matriz Python

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso através do índice de uma matriz "coluna" acessar sua linha por completo para poder fazer alteração nos índices desta linha.
A parte de coletar os índices eu consegui, mas não sei como acessar através deste índice escolhido visualizar a linha por completo.

> lista1 = [1, 6, 4, 4, 5]
>
> lista2 = [2, 2, 3, 4, 6]
>
> lista3 = [3, 9, 8, 7, 3]
>
> lista4 = [4, 7, 3, 8, 0]
>
> matriz = [lista1] + [lista2] + [lista3] + [lista4]
>
> coluna = [linha[0] for linha in matriz]
>
> print(coluna)

Então através do índice [0] [1,2,3,4], se escolho o 2[3] preciso que volte os valores [9, 8, 7, 3] para depois poder trocar algum número, 9 pelo 5 por exemplo.
Espero que tenha conseguido explicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exemplo, informei a posição da **linha** como fixa e em seguida informei a posição inicial da **coluna** até a posição final:

```
lista1 = [1, 6, 4, 4, 5]

lista2 = [2, 2, 3, 4, 6]

lista3 = [3, 9, 8, 7, 3]

lista4 = [4, 7, 3, 8, 0]

matriz = [lista1] + [lista2] + [lista3] + [lista4]

colunas = matriz[2][1:5]

print(colunas)
```

Assim vc pode obter somente os valores das colunas que vc desejar, só basta ir alterando as posições das linhas e das colunas para obter valores diferentes.

Espero que eu tenha lhe ajudado.

Mais sobre matrizes [aqui](http://programacaocompython.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/matrizes.html).

Comment: Era isso mesmo, faltava uma variável então.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho uma outra dúvida, aproveitando que é no mesmo arquivo.

Quando o usuário for escolher um número, exemplo a coluna 2, internamente o python vai trabalhar a coluna 3, fiz um teste com o código que modifiquei, fazendo o usuário pedir a coluna.

> lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> lista2 = [2, 2, 3, 4, 6]
>
> lista3 = [3, 9, 8, 7, 3]
>
> lista4 = [4, 7, 3, 8, 0]
>
> matriz = [lista1] + [lista2] + [lista3] + [lista4]
>
> numero = int(input("digite o numero: "))
>
> coluna = [linha[numero] for linha in matriz]
>
> colunas = matriz[numero][0:5]
>
> colunas[1] = 9
>
> print(colunas)

Testei a solução que já tinha achado.

> lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> lista2 = [2, 2, 3, 4, 6]
>
> lista3 = [3, 9, 8, 7, 3]
>
> lista4 = [4, 7, 3, 8, 0]
>
> matriz = [lista1] + [lista2] + [lista3] + [lista4]
>
> coluna = [linha[0]**-1** for linha in matriz] # -1 digita 2 e edita o numero 2 da coluna 1
>
> print(coluna[3])

Mas esta forma de inserir o -1 no for não funcionou no código principal.
O que falta para funcionar como esse segundo código?

Comment: Uma matriz possui Linhas e Colunas, veja o exemplo *Matriz[linha][coluna]*

Comment: Encontrei o erro, precisava inserir -1 dentro do colchete da coluna >> colunas = matriz[numero-1][0:5]. Obrigado pela ajuda, só não consigo votar na resposta.